# When is $(a^b)^c$ not equal to $a^{bc}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic, exponentiation, integers

In [this dsp.SE answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/47303), the subtle point that $e^{-j\omega t} \ne ({e^{j\omega}})^{-t}$ is made. At school I learned that $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$, which is also supported by answers like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2037831/64468).

When does it not work? Is it when $b c$ is a complex number? Or is it when $b c$ is not an integer? Or both? The linked dsp.SE answer hints at these, but I am looking for the technically strict version of the rule with all the gotchas I should be aware of.

Also, is there a name for this rule?

Comment: Whenever you write $a^b$ with $a$ not a positive real and $b$ not an integer, you are on shaky ground.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2659145/81360) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1481316/81360)

Comment: I had a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2085558/branch-points-and-branch-cuts) a while ago.

Comment: $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}\ $ holds whenever $\ a,b,c\ $ are real numbers and $a$ is positive. So, $\ bc\ $ need not be an integer. It does not hold in general in the complex numbers, which is the flaw in several fake proofs.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thank you!

Comment: @Peter Thanks, that's a pretty simple condition to keep in mind, but I get this feeling that it is slightly pessimistic... If you could write up an answer keeping the domain restriction of the numbers as minimal as possible, that would be great!